# Make GET request from Silex to external site

Tags: php, get, request, silex

I'm trying to make a GET request to an external site from my Silex application.  The only guide I can find about GET requests is the 'sub-Request' guide in the Silex documentation:
http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/cookbook/sub_requests.html

This is ignoring the base URL and looking at my application.

Does Silex have a provider which can make external GET requests?  Or do I have to use pure PHP (for example HttpRequest: http://php.net/manual/en/httprequest.send.php)

Answer (score 4):

A subrequest is not what you are looking for (Silex docs: “simulate requests against **your** application” – emphasis added).

Chances are that you don’t even need a library, as (with the default PHP configuration) you can simply use `file_get_contents()` – or other file functions – with a remote URL. You will only need a full-fledged library if you have special needs, such as setting custom headers etc.

Comment: thanks for the response.  I only need to send query data - I'll try using file_get_contents()

Comment: Good answer.  If you need something more powerful than `file_get_contents`, I suggest [Guzzle](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).  It's a clean and powerful HTTP client you can use to make any external call you need to.